# Fastest way to calculate skeleton of image in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, dynamic-programming, opencv3.0

I am using OpenCV (C++) and want to find the skeleton of an image in the fastest way.

The input image `hand_bw` is:

[image]

As of now, this is what I have:

```
cv::Mat skel(hand_bw.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));
cv::Mat temp(hand_bw.size(), CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(3, 3));
bool done; 
int i = 0;
do
{
    cv::morphologyEx(hand_bw, temp, cv::MORPH_OPEN, element);
    cv::bitwise_not(temp, temp);
    cv::bitwise_and(hand_bw, temp, temp);
    cv::bitwise_or(skel, temp, skel);
    cv::erode(hand_bw, hand_bw, element);
    double max;
    cv::minMaxLoc(hand_bw, 0, &max);
    done = (max == 0);
    i = i+1;
} while (!done);
cv::imshow("Skeleton", skel);
```

The corresponding output is:

[image]

What is the fastest way to achieve this result in C++ (probably Dynamic programming)? Time is my major constraint.

Comment: I have never met any C++ program that cannot be made faster.  So "yes".  In general?  "Make it go" is a poor SO question.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can user it, but I'm almost 100% sure there's another OpenCV way to do that operation. Anyway, have you tried refactoring that code to use Transparent API of OpenCV?

Comment: Can you post the output frame?

Comment: The obvious low-hanging fruit in this particular case is just working on a ROI of the input image that actually contains something to skeletonize...

Comment: This is a research question. There are papers written on this, although usually for a 3D scenario. Look into "Fast-Approximate Convex Decomposition"

Comment: @RicardoAlves:  I noticed that morphological operations take a very long time. Nope, I haven't tried that, never heard of using _Transparent API of OpenCV_. I'll look into it. Thanks! Please let me know any other information which you think may be useful.

Comment: @DanMašek: Thanks, that seems like a good idea. I can crop out only the part which contains my object.

Comment: @Meghana Transparent API of OpenCV is a very easy to use API which enables expensive operations (like yours) to use Hardware (such as GPU) to make it faste. Here's an easy tutorial: https://www.learnopencv.com/opencv-transparent-api/

Comment: @AndyG: well, I'm working on implementation of this algorithm too, I have come across this paper but I was searching for just a different implementation of my algorithm (using different C++ techniques), which I assume will be easier. I'll look into this again.

Comment: I have a fast implementation which runs in 1.4 ms for this image (Inteil Core i7 @3.4 GHz) (but 10.5 ms for the complementary image, that has a much larger white area). See my answer below.

Comment: @Meghana: Looking for a better/faster implementation of working code might be a candidate for the Code Review site. Looking for an algorithm might be good for Software Engineering or Robotics. SO is good for primarily solving bugs.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Is it possible to please share your implementation?

Comment: @AndyG I'll keep that in mind next time.

Comment: @Meghana: sorry, it belongs to a commercial software. But that gives you an idea of the performance that can be achieved.

Comment: @AndyG when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: There are lots and lots of implementations of skeletonization algorithms out there. Did you try to Google? I bet all of those are more efficient than what you have here.

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain an efficient solution by eroding successive layers and remembering the "fringe", i.e. the pixels that were erased at the previous iteration. So instead of processing the whole image every time, you process a much smaller subset, making the algorithm run in time quasi proportional to the image area.

When an erosion pass is performed, you keep the pixels such that erasing them would modify the local connectedness.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how the information of storing "fringe" will help? The part which has been eroded no more exists, the next iteration of erosion _has_ to be processed over the entire object again, right?

Comment: @Meghana: on any pass, only the white pixels with an heterogeneous neighborhood need to be processed. So you keep a list of these and update the list on every deletion.